# Adding a cell in a sheet with a specific column number requirement that pushes cells to the beginning of the next line

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that I need to only be 5 columns.  I use this as a teaching calendar.  Sometimes I need to add a cell in the middle if there is an activity that will add an extra day into my calendar (or what I planned for one day, actually takes two days).  However, adding a cell only pushes the row to the right and adds a new column.

Instead, I need it to keep to only 5 columns and instead move the cells to the beginning of the next row instead.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Sheets main menu, try `Insert/Row above` or `Insert/Row below`, or right click on the cell where you want the new cell and hit `Insert row`